# How to set the text direction in WebView to RTL (Right To Left)?

Tags: android, webview

Like Arabic & Hebrew and another RTL languages ,i want to set the text direction in WebView to RTL instead of default LTR .. How to make that ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add body tag then set to WebView. for example:

```html
<body dir="rtl">

</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're using Jsoup to render HTML tags,

```
Element body = document.body();
body.attr("dir", "rtl");
```